# App not launching when started after Installation from Store

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-bridge

After installing my application from the Microsoft Store, a popup comes up and asks  the user gets if he wants to start the installed appliation. However my application fails to start when launched this way. It does not have the same problem when launched directly or via the Start button inside the Microsoft Store applicaiton. The problem is i am not able to reproduce this scenario in my debuging flow. How can i debug this? Is this a known bug? I have not had this problem with other applications.

The image below shows the type of dialog that popus up after installation. When i click Starten (start). The application does not launch

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog that pops up?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with Debug -> Other Debug Targets -> Debug installed app package? My guess is that you are missing to declare your dependencies in the appxmanifest. Can  you post that section of your appxmanifest.xml file?